# How is it managed "rounding" since divide (and than multiple) returns the same amount without any loss after truncation due to rounding?

Tags: c++, math, rounding

A [test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36101691246e0a05) is easy:

```
float a= 1.0f;
float b = 1.576f;
float c = a/b;

cout << c << endl;
cout << c * b << endl;
```

Results:

```
0.634518
1
```

But `1/1.1576` is somethings like `0,63451776649746192893401015228426` (and sure much more digits).

Of course rounding happens at some time. But once the value is truncated and than multiply back, I can get the original value anyway.

Am I "lucky" or this is guaranteed every time?

Comment: cout on default displays only 6 digits of a floating point number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are lucky. You should never assume that a result of a floating point operation is of a specific value. When you compare you can use < and >, but if you want to check for equality use a small epsilon.

```
if (abs(a - b) < epsilon) cout << "a and b are equal" << endl;
```

And even if you compare, depending on the situation you also might want to use an epsilon.

You can use `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` or define your own.

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 3.9.1.8:

> The value representation of
>   floating-point types is implementation-defined

Comment: When talking about small epsilon, use std::numeric_limits<float>::epislon() so you don't have to worry about what your epsilon should be

Comment: @bazz-dee Added to my answer. But in some situations it makes sense to define a custom epsilon too. E.g. if you have a large calculation that is chaining up rounding errors.

Comment: @bazz-dee `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` is almost *never* what you want for this.  If you are comparing numbers greater than 2.0f, you might as well use straight equality. (`std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` is the smallest number which can be added to `1.0f` and give a result which is not `1.0f`.  For typical floating point representations, numbers greater than `2.0f` must either differ by twice this, or be equal.)

Answer (score 1):

You are (un)lucky.  This is absolutely not guaranteed.

Consider a floating point representation which only has space for four binary digits in the mantissa, and which doesn't suppress the leading one (because that just makes the representation more complicated, without changing the argument).

`1/10 = 0.000110011...b`  which will be `1.100B-4` in our representation.  Now multiply by ten (`1010b`), and you get `1111.B-4` in extended precision,.  If you normalize the exponent the final result is `1.111B-1` - which is *not* the same as `1.000B0`.

Similar arguments apply with longer precisions.  If you are using a x86 platform, float has 23 bits of precision (with one of them hidden), *however* the internal floating point registers have 63 bits of precision - which means that intermediate values are held *much* more precisely.  This means you can often not notice problems like this.

Comment: Since floating point arithmetic is strongly implementation dependant it is impossible to say what actually happens on binary level.

Comment: @MarioDekena.  It is possible to say what happens at a binary level *on one particular implementation*.  I imagined a particular implementation (which although it is unlikely to be successful in the market, is permitted by the standard).  I then described how it would behave, and showed that (1.0/10.)*10. would not equal 1.0.  The point being to show *why* the standard does not make that guarantee.